How to get sequence-generated value after save() for non-PK column
I have a sequence in my PostgreSQL database that generates an order_number for my orders table on insert (non-primary key column):
<createSequence
    sequenceName="order_number_seq"
    startValue="1"
    incrementBy="1"
    cacheSize="1"/>
<addDefaultValue
    tableName="orders"
    columnName="order_number"
    defaultValueComputed="nextval('order_number_seq')"/>

My issue is that after saving the order, the order_number is null:
kotlin
// Save order
order = orderRepository.save(order)
// order.orderNumber is null here

sendEmail(order)  // Need order_number here
indexOrder(order) // Need order_number here too

How can I retrieve the generated order_number value after saving? Note that this is not a primary key column.
Entity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
class Order(
    @Id val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    @Column(name = "order_number", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    var orderNumber: Long? = null,
    // other fields...
)

I tried fetching the entity with orderRepository.findById(order.id) before calling the send email and the index methods, but still doesn't work: orderNumber for order is still null
The order_number field is already insertable false

I tried doing that, but weirdly i don't have orderNumber

Yes sorry man, but why did you delete your answer? It was still an interesting read

you should flush it with saveAndFlush or you can put it into a transaction block

Do a saveAndFlush then detach the order, clear the entitymanager and do a findById. This will force a reload from the database if you don't clear the entitymanager you will get the instance cached in the entitymanager instead of a fresh one from the database.

An entityManager.refresh should work as well (and is easier) I just realized.

Update: org.hibernate.annotations.Generated is used below.
In order to apply default value on inserts, we need to remove order_number from the generated insert-SQL by using insertable = false.
Because order_number is populated by the database, @Generated is required in order to synchronize entity with database.
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
class Order(
    ...

    @Column(name = "order_number", insertable = false)
    @Generated(event = EventType.INSERT)
    var orderNumber: Long? = null,

    ...
)

Example database schema (Postgresql):
CREATE SEQUENCE order_number_seq INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE orders
(
    id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    order_number INT DEFAULT nextval('order_number_seq') NOT NULL
);


It's already insertable false, I forgot to put it, sorry about that. Even with insertable false it gives me the same error of order_number not setting in my code, but it's saved in my db

@Generated won't work on non @Id columns.

@M.Deinum I wrote a test that proved the opposite before posting this answer. BR

Which @Generated are you using? As the default JPA one doesn't work on non @Id columns.

@M.Deinum: Recreated the test, it is org.hibernate.annotations.Generated

I was only concidering the default JPA annotations and not the HIbernate one, that one does appear to be working, although not sure if tying it to a specific implementation is the best. But indeed it should work.
